# Python List Comprehensions in Dict List

Tags: python, list, dictionary, list-comprehension

I have a list that contains dicts like this:

```
[
    {'match_id': 1L, 'player_b_id': 2L, 'round_id': 1L, 'match_winner_id': 2L, 'match_date': datetime.date(2016, 3, 9), 'player_a_id': 1L, 'tournament_id': 1L}, 
    {'match_id': 2L, 'player_b_id': 4L, 'round_id': 1L, 'match_winner_id': 4L, 'match_date': datetime.date(2016, 3, 10), 'player_a_id': 3L, 'tournament_id': 1L}
]
```

and I'm wondering how can I modify each element's `'match_date'` to a string date. I know this can be accomplished using a regular loop but I'm trying to learn about list comprehensions and got stuck in this part.

I tried something like this without success:

```
matchesData = [str(v) if k == 'match_date' else v for k, v in enumerate(matchesData)]
```

Answer (score 3):

If you **must** use a list comprehension, then you must also rebuild each dictionary:

```
matchesData = [{k: str(v) if k == 'match_date' else v for k, v in d.items()} 
               for d in matchesData]
```

or use

```
matchesData = [dict(d, match_date=str(d['match_date']))
               for d in matchesData]
```

The first example uses a dictionary comprehension, that simply creates a new dictionary from the old by looping over each key-value pair. For the `'match_date'` key the values is passed through the `str()` function. This means the `match_date` key is entirely optional.

The second version *requires* `'match_date'` to exist, and creates a copy of the original dictionary with the [`dict()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict), adding in an extra key (which will replace the original `'match_date'` key-value pair from `d`).

Demo:

```
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> matchesData = [
...     {'match_id': 1L, 'player_b_id': 2L, 'round_id': 1L, 'match_winner_id': 2L, 'match_date': datetime.date(2016, 3, 9), 'player_a_id': 1L, 'tournament_id': 1L},
...     {'match_id': 2L, 'player_b_id': 4L, 'round_id': 1L, 'match_winner_id': 4L, 'match_date': datetime.date(2016, 3, 10), 'player_a_id': 3L, 'tournament_id': 1L}
... ]
>>> pprint([{k: str(v) if k == 'match_date' else v for k, v in d.items()} for d in matchesData])
[{'match_date': '2016-03-09',
  'match_id': 1L,
  'match_winner_id': 2L,
  'player_a_id': 1L,
  'player_b_id': 2L,
  'round_id': 1L,
  'tournament_id': 1L},
 {'match_date': '2016-03-10',
  'match_id': 2L,
  'match_winner_id': 4L,
  'player_a_id': 3L,
  'player_b_id': 4L,
  'round_id': 1L,
  'tournament_id': 1L}]
>>> pprint([dict(d, match_date=str(d['match_date'])) for d in matchesData])
[{'match_date': '2016-03-09',
  'match_id': 1L,
  'match_winner_id': 2L,
  'player_a_id': 1L,
  'player_b_id': 2L,
  'round_id': 1L,
  'tournament_id': 1L},
 {'match_date': '2016-03-10',
  'match_id': 2L,
  'match_winner_id': 4L,
  'player_a_id': 3L,
  'player_b_id': 4L,
  'round_id': 1L,
  'tournament_id': 1L}]
```